# convert a service to a factory in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, factory, angularjs-service

I have written the following service in angularjs, how/what do I do to change it into a factory? And also, what are the advantages/differences when a factory is used instead of a service?

```
angular.module('helloApp').service('popupService', function() {
    var popup;

    var setter = function(parameter) {
        popup = parameter;
    };

    var getter = function() {
        return popup;
    };

    return {
        setter: setter,
        getter: getter
    };
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change it, you first should declare it in your module as a factory

```
angular.module('helloApp').factory('popupService', function() {
    var popup;

    var setter = function(parameter) {
        popup = parameter;
    };

    var getter = function() {
        return popup;
    };

    return {
        setter: setter,
        getter: getter
    };
}
```

This question (factory VS service) is one of the most popular in Stackoverflow : [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

> ### Services
>
> **Syntax**: module.service( 'serviceName', function );
>
> **Result**: When
>   declaring serviceName as an injectable argument you will be provided
>   with an instance of the function. In other words new
>   FunctionYouPassedToService().
>
> ### Factories
>
> **Syntax**: module.factory( 'factoryName', function );
>
> **Result**: When
>   declaring factoryName as an injectable argument you will be provided
>   with the value that is returned by invoking the function reference
>   passed to module.factory.

### Official documentation

Also you can find official documentation on Angular website :

- [Factory definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory)
- [Service definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#service)